# Do I have to receive online payments to use Cognito forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

In order to use Cognitoforms.com free service, do I have to receive online payments or can I just use the form for collecting information only?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

You do not have to collect online payments in order to use [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/). You can collect information for RSVP or Volunteers for an upcoming event, the best part of Cognito Forms is that you can build a form that fits your needs.

If you are trying to collect payment information, then yes you would need to connect to your [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) account. This way a payment can be process safely and securely. You do not have to have a paid account in order to connect to Stripe. If your on an Individual plan we will add 1% in addition to Stripes fee to each charge.

You can also connect your PayPal account if you are on the Team plan or above.